How to convince audiences if a random selection is trully random without third party?
Suppose a YouTuber informs his viewers (audience) that he will giveaway something from a random viewer.
How does the YouTuber convince the audiences that the selection is truly random without third-party help? Which means the YouTuber has no bias to select certain viewers.
Third party, what I meant is like the YouTube platform itself, where the YouTuber performs live selections (that can be possible manipulated with screen recording).
Another third party is the random platform itself, e.g., random.org (since the seed can be manipulated).
So, it seems impossible to perform random selection without a third party.
I think there is information that he should have to tell his viewers when he informs them of this giveaway before selection. Perhaps a marker like a hash signature?
But, what is the plain data?

What you are asking is not possible in a non-interactive scenario (the YouTuber outputs a value and a "proof" that this value is random). The only way that two parties can agree on a random value which neither can influence is by performing a coin-tossing protocol. However, in the context of a YouTuber with say 1M followers, running coin-tossing with all of them seems prohibitive. As far as third parties go, you could rely on something like the NIST randomness beacon, which in my opinion is more trustworthy than random.org.

How about this:

Youtuber creates a secret string A, PKI-signs it, and publishes the signature in the initial video (together with these rules)
Participants have to submit their username U and a string B of their choice to participate and agree that their submitted data may be published later (so they should perhaps not embed profanity or nuclear codes in their B). Perhaps require between 40 and 1000 printable characters and suggest randomness or at least arbitrariness.
At the end, A is revealed, SHA256(U+A+B) is computed for every participant. Smallest value wins and is published.
Everybody can now verify that the originally published signature of A matches the now published A, that the announced hash is indeed produced by the winner's U and B, and that their own U and B produce a greater hash


The B input, is a vulnerability to increase the chance of winning I think. But if it's plain text at first, I think it's fine.

The youtuber could tell some people what A is and they could test many B to maximise their chances to win. You'd have to trust the youtuber to trust that the winner selection is random, so this doesn't work.

I think that would require a clearly defined deterministic selection algorithm taking some randomness as input. The selection algorithm would also have to give every lottery ticket an equal chance to win. An example could be encrypting all ticket numbers with the randomness as the key and selecting the ticket with the smallest ciphertext.
The randomness would have to be very difficult to manipulate and for every user to trust that to be the case. One would probably have to choose some public unpredictable value that there can only be one of. An example of such a category of values would be the one value created within some future time frame in a big distributed system that alone satisfies some property. Examples there could be the blockchain block header created within a time frame that has the smallest value, or the opening/closing value of a specific stock a specific day. One might have to combine multiple such values to reach desirable entropy levels.
And both the selection algorithm and which random number is to be used would of course have to be declared ahead of time. Those are my thoughts on this issue.

The Financial Crypto conference famously uses this method every year to determine the final submission deadline. Quoting this year's CFP: On October 4th, 2024, we project that the Ethereum's Beacon Chain will publish a random number in slot 10100000 denoted "RANDAO Reveal". Based on the last (least significant) hex character of this number, we will offer a possible extension to the paper deadline as follows:

Here is the algorithm; the hash used is SHA256.

Youtuber declares there is one selected viewer; to participate, fill out a hash of username+6969 in a form (e.g., Google Forms that can be publicly accessible read-only) and the acquisition deadline. 6969 is a nonce set by youtuber.
Viewers put its username+6969 hash, and they can see whether they already submitted it or not (due to public read-only).

hash(A_username+6969) = 3021
hash(B_username+6969) = 2519


Form closed (doesn't accept user participation anymore).
From the list of hashes, concatenate all, and then perform binary counts sorted concatenated binary, e.g., there are a total of 212 ones and 300 zeros, therefore the length of bit resulting 512, which means there 2 users participated. Perform hash as a reference with zero first and ones last (that's the protocol).

hash(000...00011111...111) = 2501

Where hash input has length 256×num_of_users.

Select winner based on closer absolute difference:

diff_A = |2501-3021| = 520
diff_B = |2501-2519| = 18 (winner)


Youtuber opens another form to reveal the winner, who can prove that the hash(username+6969) will result in an exact 2519. Here the form accepts a plain username.
There is no way that another loser that tries to become the winner can find the exact 2519 for 256-bit space from their usernames, that bruteforcing nonce (it can't since nonce is set by youtuber), only B can do this.

Note:

Here, the third party is indeed used (Google Form), but the third party here is a data acquisition facilitator, not a randomizer platform.
In case of data submission spamming to increase a chance of a viewer spamming, it can't. Every username has a same winner chance 1 out of 2^256 space, due to nonce set by youtuber.


I'm thinking that counting ones and zeroes in hashes might not be random enough to prevent manipulation, and the fact that the randomness slowly accumulates over time makes manipulation even easier. We can always see the current one-zero count and easily calculate our winning odds if $n$ new participants signed up. With only 256 possible one-zero combinations in a hash, it’s easy to evaluate all scenarios for up to many millions of additional participants. This makes it possible for someone to monitor these values and recruit friends strategically to boost their own chances of winning.

@n-l-i I might used false wording, it should have sorted concatenated binary, instead of binary counting. I still don't get it why someone can boost their own chances of winning while everyone can perform the same, so it's fair enough.

I don't quite understand your clarification. Do we not count the total number of ones and zeroes in all participant hashes and hash that to arrive at our target hash value?

I meant that the current number of ones and zeroes is known, so we calculate our hash, the other participants' hashes, and the current target hash. If someone else is closer to the target, we won't win and we will need at least one more participant to sign up. If one more signs up we get between zero and 256 new ones and the corresponding number of zeroes, 256 possibilities. We can check if we win in any of them. If two sign up there are 2*256 possibilities, etc. We can then in each moment in time calculate the ideal number of additional sign-ups to maximize our odds of winning.

@n-l-i Yes, counting the binary is unnecessary, but the sorted zeros and ones is the matter. The protocol is designed to eliminate concatenation order, e.g. hash_user_A + hash_user_B != hash_user_B + hash_user_A. So, in order to eliminate concatenation order, we can just sum all the number of occurences of zeros and ones. Then concatenate it with convention zeros first and ones last, and then get the hash of concatenated as hash reference. E.g. hash(0000...000111...11111)=2501

@n-l-i If one more sign-up in order to increase chance, the end result will be also random. Unless they can predict the hash outcome in order to minimize absolute difference from given username as hash input.

@n-l-i multiple sign-up is common vulnerabilities in order to increase the chance of being winner (if Google/Youtube allows creating multiple usernames). Regardless, everyone can perform the same, so it's fair enough.

This does not work. One problem is that anyone can determine who the winner is should there be no other entry, and then add another entry if that outcome is not deemed favorable. They can even choose that entry to favor a particular outcome, should that entry be the last. As an aside, relying on Google Forms is relying on a third party, Google.

They can even choose that entry to favor a particular outcome. How? Give me concrete example please. For the Google Form, I clarified, indeed it's third party, but just to facilitate data acquisition. It can be replaced with blockchain

@fgrieu everyone can change the winner, what's wrong with it? But are they know the username? No. Eventually, youtuber will asking viewers to reveal the plain username. If the username is fake (the youtube account doesn't exist), then simply switch to the secondary closer to reference hash.

@fgrieu Suppose party X and party Y oppose each other (rival) to taking advantage of the system with spamming submissions near submission close deadlines with random strings (instead of real usernames) until the absolute difference is minimized. It's fair enough, it creates a non-deterministic nature.

"They can even choose that entry to favor a particular outcome" by having a number of usernames at their disposal for the extra entry and entering one that gives a favorable outcome (e.g. makes the winner a member of their team). If two teams compete with this strategy, the last to enter will make their team win. It's not sure which team wins, but others won't.

I see, I think I need another step. Which is verification step, in this case audiences are asked to reveal their plain usernames. Then, perform reference hash calculation. So, the reference hash is calculated after submission closed.
